Prevent ugly hyphenation point in Danish
Apparently, with babel in Danish, the word Dynamics is allowed to be hyphenated Dynami-cs. I know I can write e.g. \babelhyphenation[danish]{dyna-mics} to prevent this, but then I’ll have to take care of all the other words that might end in “ics” as well. So I would like to address the root cause of the problem instead. Looking at the file hyph-da.tex, I suspect the line i1c is to blame. If this is the case, what should I do to change it?
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Microsoft Dynamics
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}



There is a TUG mailing list for hyphenation problems: https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen I believe that the people in charge will be happy to add 8cs. to the patterns for Danish.

Such a general rule is only possible with luatex. The following works for me:
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\babelpatterns[danish]{ 8cs. }

\begin{document}

    Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Microsoft Dynamics
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
\end{document}

By the way, now babel provides a high-level user interface to modify the ‘hyphenmins’, explained here: What’s new in babel 24.10. In this case, it can be:
\babelhyphenmins[danish]{3}{3}

Actually, in monolingual documents the optional argument with the language is not necessary.

+1. :-)  It may be worth noting that the \babelpatterns[danish]{ 8cs. } solution creates an overfull line; to be precise, just one letter (s) sticks out into the margin. To avoid this, it suffices to load the microtype package.

@Mico Using real words and not Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx can help, too .

How do you know it's not a real word in Danish?

Except in luatex you can not change patterns from normal TeX code you would have to build a new format, so for any document that you want to distribute that is likely to be rather inconvenient.
Simpler is to set \righthyphenmin (via its babel interface so babel doesn't set it back) danish uses 2 like default unlike English which uses 3

\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

% \righthyphenmin=3
\renewcommand\danishhyphenmins{33}

\begin{document}
    Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Microsoft Dynamics
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}


Apparently, \righthyphenmin=3 works in this MWE if it is used after \begin{document}.

@Gaussler yes but if babel decides to set the language back either because you locally change it or babel is just normalising the language for page headers or whatever it'll reset to what it thinks is the document default so telling babel is better in the end

@Gaussler "resetting to document defaults" is exactly what happens at \begin{document} for example, but it can happen elsewhere as well

incidentally in luatex I would have expected \patterns{8cs.} or Lua lang.patterns(lang.new(22), '8cs.') to work, they seem to add to the patterns as returned by  texio.write(lang.patterns(lang.new(22))) but have no effect on the hyphenation @Gaussler

Strange. Can you see which pattern it is that allows “cs” to be on a line by itself?

@Gaussler as you say that is i1c which being a small odd number is a weak allowing of  a break between i and c but 8cs. should add 8 (max even number) to prevent a break before a cs that occurs at the end of a word. You could try locally editing the hyphenation file then rebuilding the formats to test, then you can test also with pdflatex

Okay. Let me know when you figure out why the LuaTeX solution doesn’t work.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't think that “Dynamics” is a Danish word. If you use a foreign word in any language you should expect weird hyphenation: “dinamica” is the Italian word for “dynamics” and its hyphenation with English patterns is the unacceptable “di-nam-ica".
On the other hand, with Danish as the main language, I get
dy-na-mi-cs di-na-mi-ca spa-ghet-ti pa-ni-no gnoc-chi

which, quite surprising, has correct hyphens for all The Italian words. Not with Irish, which gives
din-am-ica dyn-am-ics spagh-e-tti pan-ino gnocchi

My suggestion is to define a \foreign command (third example below) or to also load English (for the second example).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=danish,english]{babel}

\newcommand{\foreign}[1]{\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Microsoft Dynamics
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\foreign{Microsoft Dynamics}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\foreignlanguage{english}{Microsoft Dynamics}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\end{document}


In the case you go with \foreign, you'll probably get overfull box messages, but it's better because you don't risk getting weird hyphenations and you'll know where to add soft hyphens.
By the way, if you load microtype, none of the examples above will produce overfull boxes nor require hyphenation.

Dynamics is not a Danish word, no, but it shows up every five seconds if you do ERP. So let's be fair and consider it a loanword. I'm not gonna use \foreignlanguage every time I'm gonna write it. Would you wrap the name Microsoft in \foreignlanguage?

In fact, one of the reasons the language is optional in \babelhyphenation and \babelpatterns is to enable the setting at once across all languages of the hyphenation for proper nouns and common loan words.

@Gaussler Using the suggested \foreign will show you a list of words you want to define specific hyphenation points of. For Microsoft I'd definitely go with \babelhyphenation{Micro-soft} to begin with.

Who decided that Dy-nam-ics is good hyphenation in English? How can this be more natural than Dy-na-mics?

@Gaussler Scholars in the English language?

@Gaussler Dynam-ics looks a lot more natural (and aligned with pronunciation) to me than Dyna-mics

@DavidCarlisle Well, you’re the native English speaker here, so I’ll have to trust you. But to me, the m belongs with the ics, and I cannot convince myself to think of it otherwise.

@Gaussler I'd read dyna-mics  like dynamite but dynamics is read dy nam ics
